# SQLite check constraint using char

Tags: java, sqlite, char, check-constraints

I am currently using SQLite Studio and was having trouble adding a check constraint on a column of type char. The column is a list of unique code of characters of length 5. I want the check constraint to not include the letters S , I and Z anywhere in the code. This is the code that I have written up so far,

CHECK(length(VIN) = 5) AND substr(VIN, 1, 5) NOT IN ('S','I','Z')

The code above does nothing and the letters can still be included in the code, so I decided to do the opposite although a bit longer.

(length(VIN) = 5) AND substr(VIN, 1, 5) IN ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N','O', 'P','Q', 'R', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y')

In the code above the check constraint works but no 5 length code is 'allowed' to be inserted by the constraint. Any helps on this issue would be great. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

`substr(VIN, 1, 5) NOT IN ('S','I','Z')` will always be true, because you're checking to see if a 5-character long string is not equal to one-character long strings, which will always be the case. You want a [`GLOB`](https://sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#glob) match instead:

```sql
sqlite> CREATE TABLE example(vin TEXT CHECK (length(vin) = 5 AND vin NOT GLOB '*[sSiIzZ]*'));
sqlite> INSERT INTO example(vin) VALUES ('aaaaaa'); -- Too long
Error: CHECK constraint failed: example
sqlite> INSERT INTO example(vin) VALUES ('aaaaa'); -- Just right
sqlite> INSERT INTO example(vin) VALUES ('aaaza'); -- Forbidden character
Error: CHECK constraint failed: example
```